# Docker not using cache when building on another host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**HOST 1:**

I have this simple Dockerfile in a `testcontainer` folder (no more files inside that folder):

```
FROM ubuntu:focal-20230412
RUN sleep 2.5
RUN echo "Hello" >> /test.txt
```

And build it by:

```
docker build -t mycompany/myrepo:latest .
```

Then, I get the image created:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
mycompany/myrepo   latest    ee64548693f4   2 minutes ago   72.8MB
```

Then I push it to docker hub:

```
docker push mycompany/myrepo:latest
```

**HOST 2:**

I pull the image from dockerhub:

```
docker pull mycompany/myrepo:latest
```

And then I get the image:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
mycompany/myrepo   latest    ee64548693f4   42 seconds ago  72.8MB
```

I copy the exactly same Dockerfile from the HOST 1, and put it in a local `testcontainer` empty folder, then I try to build:

```
docker build -t mycompany/myrepo:latest .
```

Instead of taking the cache and just pass the commands, it executes the commands again and creates an image with another ID:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                        TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
mycompany/myrepo   latest    b113777f192d   42 seconds ago   72.8MB
mycompany/myrepo   <none>    ee64548693f4   2 minutes ago    72.8MB
```

Why is it not taking the cache instead of building everything again??

I expect it to take cache and don't build again running the commands.

Comment: `docker pull` doesn't update the build cache.

Comment: Do you mean `pull` doesn't download the cache? If yes, do you know if it's possible to get it?